# Count or add list elements without using python built-in functions

Tags: python, list, count, sum, built-in

I have these 2 simple functions to sum and count list elements without using standard python commands like [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

```
#sum the elements of a list 
def sum_list(x):
  n=0
  for i in x:
      n= n+i
  return n
```

ex. if x=[1,5] - should return 6

```
#count the number of elements in a list 
def count_list(x):
  n=0
  for i in x:
      n= n+1
  return n
```

ex. if x=[1,5] - should return 2

The problem is I cant understand how they work. More specifically:

1) What does n=0 represents before the loop? Is it some kind of starting point?

2) After that, I can understand what the for-loop does, but I cant get what the n= n+i and n=n+1 actually means. What is "n" in this case, and why if I add "i" (n+i) gives the sum while adding "1" (n+1) gives the length of the list?

Comment: Sounds like you were taught programming too quickly and you need to revise the basics. Consider going through [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python) or some other resource from scratch. Also check out [thonny](http://thonny.cs.ut.ee/) to help you visualise  what the code is doing.

Comment: This is very basic question, which also probably won't be helpful to other people. You may want read some basic tutorials about [variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm) and [loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm).

Comment: Well.. you are absolutely right Alex Hall. They are trying to teach us programming in Python in 4 weeks and we are running like hell..!

Comment: Thanks for the links both Alex Hall and DeFazer!

Answer (score 2):

Make use of print statements to help you understand how the loop is working. (copy paste the code and run)
To answer you questions

n -> is the variable that holds the values of `n+i` and `n+1` , so value of `n+i` and `n+1` gets stored in `n` (The code moves left to right). You can think of it as a starting point

so `n+i` or `n+1` does the computation needed and stores the number in `n` and then returns it in the next step.

To answer you question "why if I add "i" (n+i) gives the sum while adding "1" (n+1) gives the length of the list?" : `i` will keep changing with every loop iteration but in `n+1` , only `n` changes everytime. Therefore sum function gives you the sum and the count function gives you the length.

You can use `len` to get the number of elements in a list

Hope this helps.

I have added more print statements to help you understand it better, run the code and see if it helps.

```
def sum_list(x):
    print("SUM FUNCTION START")    
    n = 0
    for i in x:
        print("n: ",n)
        print("i: ",i)        
        n = n + i
        print("n =",n,",","i= ",i)
        print("n + i = ",n)
        print()
    print("SUM FUNCTION END")
    print()
    return n

def count_list(x):
    print()
    print("COUNT FUNCTION START")
    n = 0
    for i in x:

        print("n: ",n)
        print("i: ",i)        
        print("n =",n,",","i= ",i)
        print("n + 1 = ",n)
        n = n + 1
        print()
    print("COUNT FUNCTION END")                
    return n

#EASIER WAY TO COMPUTER LENGTH OF THE LIST USING len FUNCTION        
def count_list2(x):
    return len(x)

def main():
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    answer = sum_list(x)
    print("Sum : ", answer)
    elements = count_list(x)
    elements2 = count_list2(x)
    print()
    print("There are", elements, "elements in the list")
    print()
    print("There are", elements2, "elements in the list")
main()
```